# Counting faces on images with opencv: Counter fails when blob is adapted to larger image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, count, blob

(Updated)

I'm building a face detection script for images in Python using opencv based on the following blog article: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/

I've added a face counter to obtain the number of face detections per image. The script works only with the example images from the blog article, but not with my own image. This is way larger, hence I change the size of the `blob`, but unfortunately this leads to counter failure. It produces the wrong number of detected faces (counts 66 but there are only 15).

Here's my code (trying to spare you the irrelevant parts):

...

```
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

(not so important. this is only to explain args["confidence"] down below)

...

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (5472,3072)), 1.0,
    (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

(input image is loaded and converted to a `blob`. I changed the original resolution of `(300, 300)` to `(5472,3072)`. The `blob` then is passed through the network to obtain the face `detections` (type = ndarray))

```
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
        y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

(not so important: detected faces are marked with rectangles and text on output image)

```
count = np.sum(detections[0, 0, :, 2] > args['confidence'])

print("[INFO]",count, "faces detected")
```

This last part counts the faces on the output image, and the weird thing is, that it doesn't correspond to the number of rectangles with text on the output image.

The documentation of `blob` and `opencv`  (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/06/deep-learning-opencvs-blobfromimage-works/) 
states that it adapts to different sizes of images simply by changing the size of the `blob`, but somehow it doesn't work.

Any ideas? I'd highly appreciate any suggestions for improvement! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How didn't it work? Did you receive an error?

Comment: Do you mean `count = np.sum(detections[0, 0, :, 2] > args['confidence'])`?

Comment: @Alistair: I didn't receive an error, just the number of counted faces was wrong. It says 66 while there are only 15. I thought it might count it exactly 4 times too often because of ```detections[0, 0, i, 2]```, but that doesn't seem to be the reason.

Comment: @a_guest: Thanks for that suggestion, it works but it also says 66 detected faces. 
I tried it with another picture, where there are 3 detections and it says 16, hence the ratio between the two numbers also varies.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it's difficult to say what's going wrong.

Comment: okay, yeah sure. I'm doing the same as in part 2 of this blog article: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/

I just checked, whether the count also fails when I go back to exactly the same code from this article and use the exact same test images, and interestingly the count is correct. That's strange however, because all that I had changed was the input image and the resolution... I'm gonna update the description with more info.

Comment: I just updated the entire question and hope it's clear now. If not, please let me know! I could of course paste the entire code, actually there's not much left that's not already here. But I guess that's not a *minimal reproducible example* either... 

The problem doesn't seem to result from the ```count``` but rather from the ```blob```. Any suggestions for improvements?